# How do make a button set a variable

Tags: java, swing

I'm coding something to work on a game and I've been having trouble trying to make a button set the variable "weapon".

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class UntitledProject {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public UntitledProject() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UntitledProject prepare = new UntitledProject();
        String weapon = prepare.weapon();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Untitled Project");
        mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                exit(0);
            }
        });
        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

        statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public String weapon() {
        headerLabel.setText("Pick Weapon");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Sword");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Lance");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Axe");
        JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");

        String weapon = "";

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                statusLabel.setText("Sword selected.");
                submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        weapon = "Sword";
                        exit(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                statusLabel.setText("Lance selected.");
                submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        weapon = "Lance";
                        exit(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                statusLabel.setText("Axe selected.");
                submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        weapon = "Axe";
                        exit(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        controlPanel.add(button1);
        controlPanel.add(button2);
        controlPanel.add(button3);
        controlPanel.add(submitButton);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I need for when the submit button is pressed the weapon variable is changed to what button was pressed before the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Make an instance variable.

```
private JPanel controlPanel; // under this line 
private String weapon;
```

Then everywhere else, remove String in front of `weapon` because this makes a **new, local** variable.

Then, you can remove this line

```
String weapon = "";
```

To set the sword, for example, use `UntitledProject.this.weapon` to explicitly set the instance variable.

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            statusLabel.setText("Sword selected.");
            UntitledProject.this.weapon = "sword";
```

Do the same for the other buttons.

Then, additionally, the submit button only needs it's action to be set once, not everytime you set a weapon.

```
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            statusLabel.setText("Axe selected.");
            UntitledProject.this.weapon = "Axe";
        }
    });
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            exit(0);
        }
     });
```

And, does this app only pick one weapon, then exit?

```
exit(0);
```

This tells your **whole app** to quit with a 0 (success) code, not just close the current window

And since weapon is moved to an instance variable,  you can change this to a `void` method (you weren't returning anything anyways)... Change

```
public String weapon() {
```

To

```
public void weapon() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a temp weapon variable to record the previously selected choice. Once a user selects a weapon update the weapon varible and the temp. Once submit is clicked assign temp to weapon variable and visa versa